# how to know when a parent menu item contains an active child

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a menu structured this way:

```
menu item 1

menu item 2
    submenu item 1
    submenu item 2

menu items 3
```

what I would like to do is:

- Showing only the shallower level (1st, menu item 1,2,3) when I'm not on any submenu page.
- When I'm on submenu item 2 I would like the submenus to be expanded and the first level item highlighted (simple one)
- When I'm on a second level menu item (i.e. submenu item 2) I would like the submenu expanded, plus the submenu item highlighted (difficult one)

Keep in mind that I'm overriding the template showing this menu, so any template modification is in order :-)

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Can be achieved using CSS. Please show us you have tried to solve this on your own by providing some code

Comment: @Lodder I think I can't because when a submenu item is "active" I don't have any information about that on the parent item

Comment: In which case, jQuery will be your friend for that situation

Comment: @Lodder you're right, but can I do this with joomla? Isn't there a "back end" way to accomplish this? For example, a new information along with "active", like "childActive" would be awesome. By setting "active" on the first menu item could be more thank ok

Comment: No, there is no default option in Joomla to do this. This is a template query, therefore you will need to manually add your own code

Comment: any php hardcode suggestion? (I'm choosing the jquery way though)

Comment: As mentioned before, please show that you have made the effort by trying to tackle the problem on your own and provide some code.